# How can I fix the error in indexed DB "Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value. "

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

```
var db;

var request = window.indexedDB.open("Reading Multi Datas", 1);

request.onupgradeneeded = function (ev) {

  db = ev.target.result;
  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("users", { keyPath: "ui" });
};

request.onsuccess = function (ev) {

  db = ev.target.result;

  var transaction = db.transaction("users", "readwrite");

  var userObjectStore = transaction.objectStore("users");

  var users = [

    {
      ui: "p12kl58!",
      firstName: "M",
      latsName: "A",
      age: 38,
      isMarried: true,
      childrens: 1,
    },
    {
      ui: "85ph56kfg",
      firsName: "A",
      lastName: "B",
      age: 55,
      isMarried: false,
      childrens: null,
    },
    {
      ui: "6538jkg23",
      firstName: "E",
      lastName: "T",
      age: 52,
      isMarried: true,
      childrens: 3,
    },
    {
      ui: "25lp634gs",
      firstName: "A",
      lastName: "M",
      age: 49,
      isMarried: true,
      childrens: 2,
    },
    {
      ui: "6578lppo",
      firstName: "L",
      lastName: "T",
      age: 51,
      isMarried: true,
      childrens: 2,
    },
  ];

  var request = userObjectStore.add(users); // Here it shows that the error may be ??

  request.onsuccess = function () {
    console.log("User's successfully add", request.result);
  };

  request.onerror = function () {
    console.log("Error: ", request.error);
  };

  var usersData = db.transaction("users").objectStore("users");

  var answer = (usersData.openCursor().onsuccess = function (ev) {
    var cursor = ev.target.result;

    if (cursor) {
      let infoUsers = cursor.value;
      console.log(infoUsers.uid);
      console.log(infoUsers.firstName);
      console.log(infoUsers.lastName);
      console.log(infoUsers.age);
      console.log(infoUsers.isMarried);
      console.log(infoUsers.childrens);
      cursor.continue();
    }
  });
};

request.onerror = function (ev) {
  console.log("Error: ", ev.target.error);
};
```

I'm trying to create a indexed DB, but I keep hitting of the same problem. Can any of you guys help me with an advice please?

this is the exception name: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value.
at IDBOpenDBRequest.request.onsuccess"

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to add that whole array as one object, and the error message happens because it's failing to find the "ui" property on the array itself.

You need to call `userObjectStore.add` for each object in `users`. There is no API to bulk add a list of objects at once. Then wait until the "complete" event from the transaction to know when it's done.